# Firebase Topic Not Found

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

We are developing some kind of community feature in our app. It kind of works like Reddit.
We want to subscribe each user, with its push token, to each group within a community once their join the community.

We are using Firebase Admin SDK to perform the topic subscription like this:

```
topic = f'/topic/organisation/12345/group/12345'
response = messaging.subscribe_to_topic(user.push_token, topic)
```

But when we look at the response we get a 'NOT_FOUND' from the api as a reason.
When I look at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/topic/list I do not see the topics.

When searching online some people say that it takes around 24 hour for the topic to be created.

So my questions are:

1. how long does it take for a topic to be created?
2. when we subscribe a user to a not existing topic, will the user be subscribed to it once it is created?
3. why are the topics not created instantly?
4. where can I list the topics?

Thanks in advance.

Theo